# How much energy does a neuron use for information processing as opposed to just surviving?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

That is, as part of a neural network in a brain.

Comment: Are you interested in theoretical or experimental information? Checking the [Bionumbers](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/) database for experimental data: [glucose consumption averaged per neuron ](http://kirschner.med.harvard.edu/files/bionumbers/Glucose%20consumption%20averaged%20per%20neuron.pdf).

Comment: There are many, many different types of neurons. Some of them show very high spontaneous firing rates, while others are pretty silent. I think @Mustang's is great, but this question needs clarification.

Comment: Mainly interested from a theoretical computer science POV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://quantum-mind.co.uk/anaesthetics-and-brain-energy/

About 80% of the brain’s energy consumption is devoted to neuronal firing with only 20% involved in maintenance activity.

The energy for firing is mainly supplied by glia and astrocytes, the maintenance of the neuron itself is done mainly by the cellular machinery in the neuron.

Comment: The text literally says "neural signalling", which is a lot broader than APs only. Without other references you may want to edit the wording. +1 nonetheless, nice way to tackle such a broad question.